# Compiling java class from non-java file

Tags: java, compilation, code-generation

I have a set of ruby files where I have some string of type:

```
@something = [Whatever.new('1rabbit'), 
              Whatever.new('2rabbit'), 
              Whatever.new('3rabbit')]
```

I would like to parse out this information from the ruby file during compilation phase (javac run with maven - but i think it is no difference how javac is run), and create a .class enum of type:

```
public enum Something {
  1RABBIT,
  2RABBIT,
  3RABBIT
}
```

and store it into the target folder. Then, I can use this enum whatever I want (after this initial compilation). I looked into AnnotationProcessors, and bytecode generation, but the first requires annotations, and the second is done during runtime. And I cannot find out how to do it properly.

What is the correct tool to do this, and how?

Comment: Why don't you just use JSON and parse it into a Java program?

Comment: I have some legacy code in ruby files. My example is just a simplification

Answer (score 2):

`maven`s life cycle has a *generate sources* phase. There you cold use the `exec-maven-plugin` to run a script generating the enums.